# What kind of shower valve is this

Tags: shower, valve

I've got a lot of rust coming out when I run the shower or fill the tub.

I've taken the valve apart as far as I feel comfortable taking it.  Can someone help identify what type of valve this is? (See photo)[image: shower valve]

It's a diverter type for tub/shower.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the knob? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: the valve looks in pretty good shape. I doubt the valve is the source of your problem.  Have you done any repiping or other plumbing work? Is the rust showing up in any other areas of the house?

Comment: The valve is brass, it is not going to have anything to do with rust. Rust only comes from iron / steel. If you have galvanized steel pipes, you are going to have rust.

Comment: When I turn the tap on, rusty water comes out, it's so dark it looks like orange juice!  I don't think the rust comes from the fixture itself, just that iron filings or debris have become stuck in the valve.  They did some water main work on my street and I had to clear all the aerators in the house.  I haven't been able to dissemble this fixture yet.  I'm not sure if I need to replace the cartridge, or just to disassemble it and flush the debris out.